# How do you define something so that VScode can assume it is defined (preprocessor)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

One of the multiple features of vscode is that when using C or C++ code and we have

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
this
and this
#endif
```

if `SOMETHING` is not defined the code appears shadowed.
That is fine and dandy. I know you can set that in the time of building (so my question is *not that*) but I want to read the code as if `SOMETHING` is defined.
So my question is how can I make VSCode assume that that `SOMETHING` is defined?

right now I am just putting a comment on the #ifdef but I don't think that is a suitable way of doing this

Comment: add `#define SOMETHING 1` at the top of the file, or you can look at the `c_cpp_properties.json` file if you can set some defines for the language server

Comment: is this c_cpp_properties.json a configuration file for vscode?